# Fixing arguments when using pmap in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, pmap

I have defined a function `f(x, y, z)` in `Julia` and I want to parallely compute `f` for many values of `x`, holding `y` and `z` fixed. What is the "best practices" way to do this using `pmap`?

It would be nice if it was something like `pmap(f, x, y = 5, z = 8)`, which is how the `apply` family handles fixed arguments in `R`, but it doesn't appear to be as simple as that. I have devised solutions, but I find them inelegant and I doubt that they will generalize nicely for my purposes.

- I can wrap `f` in a function `g` where `g(x) = f(x, y = 5, z = 8)`. Then I simply call `pmap(g, x)`. This is less parsimonious than I would like.
- I can set 5 and 8 as default values for `y` and `z` when `f` is defined and then call `pmap(f, x)`. This makes me uncomfortable in the case where I want to fix `y` at the value of some variable `a`, where `a` has (for good reason) not been defined at the time that `f` is defined, but will be by the time `f` is called. It works, but it kind of spooks me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good solution, which turns your apparently inflexible first option into a flexible one, is to use an *anonymous* function, e.g.

```
g(y, z) = x -> f(x, y, z)

pmap(g(5, 8), x)
```

or just

```
pmap(x -> f(x, 5, 8), x)
```

In Julia 0.4, anonymous functions have a performance penalty, but this will be gone in 0.5.

Comment: Oh yes, I am looking forward to the removal of the performance penalty, been following the discussion [on github](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1864) for a while now.